# AppFog node.js client cannot load socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, appfog

I just deployed a node.js site to AppFog. It works fine locally when I go to "http://localhost:8080", but when I got to the one on AppFog: http://bandwithfriends.aws.af.cm/ I get the following Chrome console error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1357769454152. Origin http://bandwithfriends.aws.af.cm is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

**SERVER CODE:**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    static = require('node-static'); // for serving files

// This will make all the files in the current folder
// accessible from the web
var fileServer = new static.Server('./');


app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8080);

io.configure('development', function(){
  io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
});
```

**CLIENT CODE index.html:** 
I am including socket.io like this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

**CLIENT CODE script.js:**

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080';
var socket = io.connect(url);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, what is `handler` in `var app = require('http').createServer(handler),` I tried using your code and it is not defined

Comment: Make sure you include the handler function: function handler (request, response) {

 request.addListener('end', function () {
        fileServer.serve(request, response); // this will return the correct file
    });
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I had to do to fix this was remove the url on the client side code:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

Hope this helps anyone else having the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

Both your client side and server side are wrong.

On the client side; make this change:

```
var url = io.connect('http://<your domain name>');
//For example: var url = io.connect('http://shash7.ap01.aws.af.cm');
```

On the server side, you need to implement socket.io like this:

```
var app = require('express')()   , server =
require('http').createServer(app)   , io =
require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(80);
```

The above code was taken from the socket.io site. They changed the way socket.io listens in the 0.9 version so use the above version.

Other than that, everything looks fine. Tell me if you still can't figure this out.

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer. I was looking for a way to do this without express, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Without express? Didn't see that. My Bad.

Comment: No worries, I still gave you an upvote ;). Thanks for the help!